# JQuery mobile page refresh not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using j query Mobile for my app . I have multiple pages in single index file . i need to change page using jquery mobile change page

```
  $.mobile.changePage('#test', { 
            transition: 'slideup',
            reloadPage: true

        } );
```

but my condition is to refresh #test page on change page but reloadPage will simply go to my first page . how to refresh a particular page in jquery mobile pages where i use data-role = "page" and i change page by id
Reload page goes to first  data role first page